# Conditional Filters

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

It would be good to have conditional filters available. Correct if I am wrong but right now if I setup a filter with [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone), [web-service](/questions/tagged/web-service) and [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) I would get notifications if any of those gets a hit. In other words, is always an 'OR' condition.

Would be nice to be able to filter like:

- Filter: [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) && [web-service](/questions/tagged/web-service)
- Filter: [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) && ( [restkit](/questions/tagged/restkit) || [asihttprequest](/questions/tagged/asihttprequest) )

Comment: I'm interested in Installers but only on Windows. My filters currently show installer related questions for android and other things I don't care about. It would be good to have a NOT operator so you can easily exclude tags.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote your question, but I like this feature request. It was the first thing I hoped it would do: AND

Comment: Just up-voted your awesome comment :)

Comment: I like it too. Upvoted.