# Is there a way to have multiple favorite/ignored tag sets?

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

...aside from creating multiple accounts just to be able to see the "right" questions.

Use case:

On some days I have more spare time and would like to see a broader selection on various topics.

On other days I have to stay focused and would like to see just a narrow selection of questions related to the tasks Im currently working on.

A tedious workaround would be to manually adapt the filter sets.

I have found [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105025/conditional-filters) which might look similar, but it's a different issue as I'm asking for separate sets of tags regardless of conditional operators on them.

Comment: `...aside from creating multiple accounts...` Do I need to comment that idea?

Comment: Well, my first idea was to do this via the API...but that's not possible. Maybe we can get an API for editing user-preferences (only our own, of course) like these tags.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby - I didn't expect the "multiple accounts idea" would be taken seriously. Next time i'll add a smiley ;)

Comment: Ouh...don't take it personal, we've got a lot of odd people stumble in here with odd ideas on how SE works and should work. ;)

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby - np

Comment: The ideal solution would be http://stackexchange.com/filters/ with negative tags and/or an API call. However, the closest thing now is to use a 2nd account. The rep is not lost because it's possible to merge accounts at any time. I avoid switching accounts using a 2nd browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view tagged questions for a given set by using the `[or]` tag when searching, or by manually constructing a tagged-questions URL by joining tags with `+or+`:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+plone+or+jquery
```

would give me all questions tagged `python`, `plone` *or* `jquery`. If you typed `[python] [or] [plone] [or] [jquery]` in the search box you would get the same URL.

Bookmark that URL and you can construct predefined 'favourite sets'.

Comment: Although the asker probably wanted a built in option.

Comment: @Inkbug: Yeah, but that doesn't mean the existing options aren't handy. :-)

Comment: That's why I upvoted. :-)

Comment: Thanks Martijn, +1. Thats halfway there. Can I make it work the other way round - for ignoring questions? Neither `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not+python+not+plone` nor `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+and+not+plone` seem to work

Comment: Unfortunately, no. SE does not have a negative search option (see http://stackoverflow.com/search for the options that are supported).